# How to make this code compile?

Tags: c

// File: foo.c

```
static int var;

void foo()
{
var++;
}
```

// end of file foo.c

// File bar.c:

```
static int var;

void bar()
{
var++;
}
```

// end of file bar.c

// file main.c

```
static int var;
void main()
{
foo();
bar();
printf("%d", var);
}
```

// end of file main.c

Question: Will the above program compile ? If so what will be the result ?

I tested the code and found it couldn't be compiled. I try to use extern in main.c to use the function foo() and bar() but it still couldn't be compiled.

Comment: Does it work better using `int main()` instead of `void main()`?

Comment: @nvl: It should be zero. Separate the files correctly.

Comment: You need to post (a) the commands that you use to try and build this and (b) the error messages that you got from the compiler and/or linker

Comment: @skydoor: What compiler are you using? Are you sure you aren't compiling C code with a C++ compiler?

Comment: The phrasing of this question sounds like homework

Comment: @Isak: Why should it matter for this case. Nobody is writing code for OP. I think it's perfectly OK to help people get started in compiling their code. Otherwise, how else they can try writing their own programs?

Comment: @nvl: because `var` is static, and thus should be local to each file. Therefore, the `var` in main.c should be untouched from `foo` and `bar` since they each have their own `var` variable. This is also the behavior I get from GCC 4.2.1.

Comment: @nvl: why on *earth* would you want to do that ?

Comment: @Paul: I actually misunderstood OP, and thought he was doing it this way.. :| never mind

Comment: @Mehrdad: nothing wrong. I just like to see questions tagged properly so that I know how to best help him. If it's homework, that means I should spend more time explaining the basic and not just focus on the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

main.c has a few minor problems - it should be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int var;

extern void foo();
extern void bar();

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    bar();
    printf("%d\n", var);
    return 0;
}
```

It should build OK like this:

```
$ gcc -Wall main.c foo.c bar.c -o main
```

and the result should be:

```
$ ./main
0
```

Comment: GCC actually compiles it with `main.c` as written in the question. It just throws warnings about implicit declaration on `printf` and `main` return type.

Comment: Why is `extern` needed on the function prototypes?

Comment: @jleeddev: extern is not strictly necessary in this context but it is considered by some to be good style

Comment: @skydoor - yes, the `extern` becomes implicit in a function prototype if you omit it, just like `int` can be implicit in some contexts.

Answer (score 4):

I would expect it to compile and print 0 (though if you want to compile it as C++, you'll have to add declarations for `foo()` and `bar()`, and in either C or C++, you might get a warning that `main()` should really return an int).

Since `var` is defined as static in each of the three files, you really have three separate variables that all happen to have the same name. Perhaps it's easiest to think of each file as defining a struct that contains its static variables. What you've done is called `foo()`, which increments `foo.var`. Then you've called `bar()`, which increments `bar.var`. Then you've printed out `main.var`, which was initialized to zero, and never modified.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles for me (although with a warning about the return type from `main()`).

The result, in terms of what `main()` will print, is undetermined because you have not initialized the value of `var` in main.c. The most likely result when the compiler is invoked without optimizations is zero because the OS will have zeroed the physical memory supplied to the process for data storage (the OS does this to avoid leaking confidential data between processes).

The static qualifier to the `var` variable definitions means that the variable is not visible outside the source file it is defined in. It also means that each of the three `var` variables gets its own storage location.

If we add a `printf("[module name] *var=%p\n", &var)` to `foo()`, `bar()` and `main()` respectively to print the address of the memory location that stores those three variables you should get something like this:-

```
foo() *var=0x8049620
bar() *var=0x8049624
main() *var=0x8049628
```

Note that each variable gets its own storage location. The code in each source file will access the version of var that is specific to to that source file. Using `static` like this in .c files is typically used to implement the concept of information hiding in C.

Answer (score 0):

The code (as it is) will compile and result will be 0 (as Jerry explains) because `static` variable will have file scope.

But, if you include `foo.c` and `bar.c` in `main.c`, and compile as

```
gcc main.c
```

then the result will be `2` because there will only be one global variable `var`.